# Безопасность запросов в MongoDB из C# приложения

Tags: c#, mongodb, безопасность

Прошу дать совет или разъяснение. Есть C# (VB.Net) приложение. Оно проводит операции с базой данных MongoDB. В приложении имеется строка подключения к базе данных в виде:

```
Dim ConnectionString = "mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@cluster.ru/"
```

Какие в этом случае могут быть проблемы с безопасностью? Дело в том, что дезасемблировав приложение можно узнать эту строку. Или снифить трафик например, то можно узнать параметры и получить доступ к базе данных.
Как в таком случае проектируются приложения подобного рода?

Comment: В таких случаях просят данные у самого пользователя. Например если идет чистая работа с базой, то просите ввести пользователя его учетные данные от базы данных. Если идет что то более серьезное, то я вам советую сделать серверную прослойку, может какой нибудь WebAPI, который будет принимать простые запросы и работать с базой сам. То есть перенести всю логику базы на сторону сервера. Так вы будете точно защищены от потерь. А зашивать в код... C# не блещет к сожалению надежностью и даже хорошо зашифрованный код можно спокойно вскрыть.

Comment: Да, но если сделать прослойку в виде какого-то API возникают все теже вопросы. Допустим мы передаем в параметрах запроса или в боди параметры аутентификации что-то вроде /api/read/:user/:pass - то в таком случае все те же вопросы как с безопасностью? Ведь можно дергать апишку как вздумается проснифирив трафик типичных операций. Как апишку прикрывать в таком случае?

Comment: А почему вы хотите передавать учетные данные пользователя в открытом виде?  Для таких целей используют например JWT токены, который также генерирует сервер. Для большей безопасности выдается 2 токена, Acess - токен с минимальным сроком жизни, используется пр доступе к нужному API. Refresh - токен с более длительным сроком, используется в момент получения нового Acess токена. В общем ваша задача убрать/минимизировать отправку логина/пароля напрямую. Поймите одно, нету 100% защищенных серверов. Я например 80% сайтов могу спокойно автоматизировать, эмулируя их авторизацию путем отлова оригинала.

Comment: Спасибо, я хотел услышать вот что-то такое, чтобы сформировать понимание более защищенного обмена данными между хранилищем и приложением. Я понимаю что при желании можно ломануть что угодно. Просто хотелось бы изначально построить приемлемую архитектуру приложения.

Comment: Ну вот с самого начала и забудьте про передачу пароля через запросы в открытом виде и также не храните их в открытом виде где либо (в базе, на компьютере пользователя или еще где). Используйте хэш (например не `pass`, а `9d4e1e23bd5b727046a9e3b4b7db57bd8d6ee684`). Ну в общем я думаю вы поняли.